# global varible in class functions

Tags: php, oop, global

1. I got some old code to deal with, it's to large to rewrite
2. I need to extend and/or replace some pieces of it
3. In the code, there is a declared variable `$table_prefix` (not global) used in SQL queries like this:

   ```
   $sql="SELECT * FROM {$table_prefix}table WHERE id = %d";
   ```
4. `$table_prefix` changes depending on some conditions (i.e host, remote ip etc)

**The problem**

to get my goals  I created a class with many functions reading/writing data to SQL. For now I had to repeat `global $table_prefix` in every function. It looks similar to this:

```
class MyClass {

    function loadData($id=0){

        global $table_prefix;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table_prefix}table WHERE id = %d;";
        [...]
    }

    function saveData($id=0, $data){

        global $table_prefix;

        if(is_array($data) [...] ){
            $sql = "UPDATE
                 {$table_prefix}table
                SET
                    data_1= %s,
                    data_2 = %d
                WHERE id = %d;";
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

**QUESTION** 
Is there any way to declare this `$table_prefix` once and use it in every class function without repeating it.

***protip*** If you see an mistake in my English, feel free to write me about it - i'm still learning, and learning, and learning... It seems it's been that way forever, and not only with my language skills, becouse people learn whole life :)

Comment: `public function __constructor() { global $table_prefix; $this->table_prefix = $table_prefix; }` then use it in your methods?

Comment: your code _could be_ vulnerable to SQL injection,,, just and advice.

Comment: it's so simple solution- checking if it works
@Pipe yeap, i know in this example it looks like it is ;)

Comment: @Federkun can you add your solution as an answer - it's simplest and effective in this case so it's snipp i actually use :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this in the constructor of your class:

```
 class MyClass {
     private $table_prefix;

     public function __construct($table_prefix) {
            $this->table_prefix = $table_prefix;
     }
     private function table($name) {
           return $this->table_prefix.$name;
     }
     function loadData($id=0){             
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->table("table")." WHERE id = %d;";
        //Or you can not define the function and do the following:
        //$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->table_prefix."table WHERE id = %d;";
        [...]
    }

     ...         

}
```

You will then need to construct your class differently:

```
 $class = new MyClass($tablePrefix); //Where $tablePrefix is the prefix you've computed
```

Comment: almost the same thing as @Federkun proposed, his solution is a bit better, becouse he "import" this global.

Comment: @Anielka avoid using `global` in PHP. It's bad.

Comment: @Anielka I would recommend having strong painkillers on hand then.

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest you to use the `Define` function in your configuration phase to define `table_prefix` globally.

Sample code:

config.php

```
<?php define('table_prefix','prefix_');
```

MyClass.php

```
$sql = "UPDATE " . table_prefix . "...";
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: He is writing `OOP`, I don't think this is the best solution for the way he is coding.. (I'm not the downvoter, just giving a possible explanation).

Comment: YEAH! Fight globals vars with other global stuff!

Comment: Well, looking at the question: `Is there any way to declare this $table_prefix once and use it in every class function without repeating it.`
It pretty much answers the question, otherwise your comment with a property answers provides an alternative.

Comment: not this case:
1. `$table_prefix` depends form some conditions (and i don't want to investigate whole code where and why)
2. I need it "in class global" to use in my methods not "project global"
3. my need is to use this "{$table_prefix}" as is and not repleacing it (to many places, not my oryginal code)
4. i really don't want to  fight fire with fire.